# Python's getattr gets called twice?

Tags: python, reflection, python-2.6, getattr

I am using this simple example to understand Python's **getattr** function:

```
In [25]: class Foo:
   ....:     def __getattr__(self, name):
   ....:         print name
   ....:         
   ....:         

In [26]: f = Foo()

In [27]: f.bar
bar
bar
```

Why is `bar` printed twice? Using Python 2.6.5.

Comment: What version are you using. It works for me as expected on 2.6.5 with both new and old style classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's due to IPython.

To "fix" it, you have to disable autocall: `%autocall  0`

> It's an inevitable side-effect of
>   %autocall: since it has to analyze the
>   object in the command line to see if
>   it's callable, python triggers getattr
>   calls on it.

Source: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2008-June/005562.html

Answer (score 3):

You're also using IPython. The stock CPython REPL doesn't exhibit this behavior.